# how to slice an image in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to slice images in my html document using CSS.

Here is how I want to slice the image. I've masked it with red color:

[image]

```html
<div class="img_section" >
  <img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/1zbcqhg.jpg"  alt="sliced-image" >
</div>
```

I don't want to use a mask layer to hide the image, because the background of document is not a solid color. I used border-radius property to do it but I couldn't. If it's not possible with CSS , so isn't it possible with js too?

Answer (score 5):

You could do this using `svg`'s `clipPath` to clip the image and `foreignObject`to import the html within `svg`, since you could only apply `svg` `clipPath` to a `svg` element.

```html
<svg width="445" height="257">
  <clipPath id="clip">
    <path d="M0,0 h444 l-130,257 h-314z" />
  </clipPath>
  <foreignObject clip-path="url(#clip)" width="445" height="257">
    <div class="img_section">
      <img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/1zbcqhg.jpg" alt="sliced-image" />
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: @AdrianEnriquez - `svg` `clipPath` has better browser compatibility.

Comment: sorry @chipChocolate.py I thought It was the same.

Comment: You are back !  Welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with CSS layer max, I wrote an example to create what you want, overlayed with black mask.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="img_section" >
  <img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/1zbcqhg.jpg"  alt="sliced-image" >
  <div class="image-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img_section{
    width:445;
    height:257px;
    position:absolute;
}
.image-arrow{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 257px solid black;
    border-left: 130px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way in CSS to slice the images this can only be done in LESS and SASS but you can use multiple images as a sprite (single image multiple icon)

[Check this out](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprites-with-background-positioning)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I think you may be looking for `clip-path`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Browser support is rather patchy (as of July 2015), however. http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path